# Ошибка в AJAX форме

Tags: jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь сделать AJAX форму отправки сообщений с сайта.

Переменной formCost присваиваю содержимое элемента #modal_callback_2 через .html().

При нажатии на кнопку "Отправить" ничего не происходит.

Код прикрепляю:

```js
$(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    var $formCost = $("#modal_callback_2").html();

    $formCost.on("click", 'button.submit', function () {

        var strName = $('#name', $formCost).val(),
            strCompany = $('#company', $formCost).val(),
            strMail = $('#mail', $formCost).val(),
            strPhone = $('#phone', $formCost).val();

        if (strPhone.length < 4) {
            $('#phone', $formCost).trigger('focus');
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/callback_ajax.php',
                data: {
                    name: strName,
                    company: strCompany,
                    mail: strMail,
                    phone: strPhone
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<div id="modal_callback_2" class="form cost" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form_wrap">
        <span class="form_title">Узнать стоимость</span>
        <form id="order_cost">
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
            <input type="text" id="company" placeholder="Название компании">
            <input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Ваше E-MAIL">
            <input type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Ваше телефон">
            <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <button type="button" class="submit">Отправить</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $formCost = $("#modal_callback_2"); // no html();
```

`$().html()` возвращает строку, соответствующую свойству `innerHTML`, это здесь не нужно.

Comment: Абсолютно точно, спасибо.

Comment: @АндрейМаксимов Пожалуйста. Успехов!